# Why is there a big difference in the CPU usage of sleep(1) between Windows and macOS/Linux?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, cpu-usage

I observed that the CPU usage of `while true sleep(1)` differs greatly between Windows and macOS/Linux.

Linux/macOS: The code below will cause high CPU, even showing 130%+ CPU usage in `top`. (My CPU has 4 cores, so the total in `top` is 400%.)

Windows: To my surprise, it just shows 0% CPU usage in Windows Task Manager.

So... what is the reason?

There are Java and C# versions of the code; they show similar results.

#### Java

```java
/**
* Platform=openjdk 11, test in CentOS7.5/macOS11/Windows7
*/
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while (true) {
                            Thread.sleep(1);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();
        
            if(i == 100)
                thread.join();   
        }
    }
}
```

#### C#

```cs
/**
* sdk=NET5, test in CentOS7.5/macOS11/Windows7
*/
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var threadList = new List<Thread>(100);
        foreach (var index in Enumerable.Range(1, 100))
        {
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            });
            thread.Start();
            threadList.Add(thread);
        }

        threadList[0].Join();
    }
}
```

---

### 2021.5.8

I've implemented goroutine version of this demo, it just used less than 5% CPU usage at CentOS7. So can I consider the CPU usage was consumed by the context switching of Linux LWP?

#### Go

```golang
package main

import (
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go sleep()
    }
    runtime.Gosched()

    wg.Add(1)
    wg.Wait()
}

func sleep() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
    }
}
```

Comment: A better question might be: how long is it actually sleeping for on the two platforms? At a guess Linux is probably busy-waiting (spinning in a loop) to get the 1ms (too short for a real thread-sleep), whereas Windows puts the thread to sleep and wakes it up well after the 1ms timeout

Comment: I used `strace` to trace system call of these threads in centos, I see `FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE` and `FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE` syscall switch rapidly, It seems not only spin @Charlieface

Comment: Well, 1ms is not totally unrealistic for a kernel timed wait.  Signaling/scheduling latencies, (on Windows, anyway.  I don't expect that linux is much different), are in the order of 10us, so it is quite reasonable to remove CPU for ~1ms.